# initializing ruby singleton

Tags: ruby, singleton, initialization, rubymotion

I'm trying to initializing a singleton in ruby. Here's some code:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :var_i_want_to_init

  # singleton
  @@instance = MyClass.new
  def self.instance
    @@instance
  end

  def initialize # tried 1. initialize, 2. new, 3. self.initialize, 4. self.new
    puts "I'm being initialized!"
    @var_i_want_to_init = 2
  end
end
```

The problem is that initialize is never called and thus the singleton never initialized. I tried naming the init method initialize, self.initialize, new, and self.new. Nothing worked. "I'm being initialized" was never printed and the variable never initialized when I instantiated with

```
my_var = MyClass.instance
```

How can I setup the singleton so that it gets initialized? Help appreciated,

Pachun

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rubymotion (1.24+) now seems to support [using GCD for singleton creation](http://blog.rubymotion.com/post/31917526853/rubymotion-gets-ios-6-iphone-5-debugger)

```
class MyClass
  def self.instance
    Dispatch.once { @instance ||= new }
    @instance
  end
end
```

Comment: Good to know, but hardly relevant

Comment: @sardaukar How is this not relevant? This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @RyanRomanchuk RubyMotion is a very different runtime to MRI. That's why I said that it's not really relevant as an answer to a Ruby question. Ans also - this particular answer is Mac OS X only. Right?

Comment: Oh, the OP tagged rubymotion, I assumed this was a RM question, not ruby.

Answer (score 18):

There's a [standard library for singletons](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/singleton/Singleton):

```
require 'singleton'

class MyClass
  include Singleton
end
```

To fix your code you could use the following:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :var_i_want_to_init

  def self.instance
    @@instance ||= new
  end

  def initialize # tried 1. initialize, 2. new, 3. self.initialize, 4. self.new
    puts "I'm being initialized!"
    @var_i_want_to_init = 2
  end
end
```

Comment: I should have said I don't have access to standard libs because it's [rubymotion](http://rubymotion.com/). But the second method worked, so thank you very much.

Comment: I can't believe RubyMotion comes without support for the standard libraries. There's limited support for gems, but Ruby without the standard libraries isn't that exciting as an alternative for Obj-C: No sockets, no JSON, no …?

Comment: Apple does a lot of this: Plenty of socket libs (AFNetworking CFSocket), NSJSONSerialization, etc. And people are beginning to package all these apple provided libs in a more ruby-like syntax. Look up "ruby motion bubblewrap"

Comment: How do you initialize instance variables when using the standard Singleton module?